# How to update a database with +1

Tags: php

I would like that for "salade", when I click on the button "+"  It add me    +1 on my stock.

For example, I have a 25 salade available,  When I click on "+"  I have now 26 salades,

Here my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['stock'])){
    $stock = $_POST['stock'];
    $stock = $stock +1;
}
?>
```

```
<?php $req=$db->prepare("UPDATE ingredients SET stock =:stock WHERE nom = 'salade'");
                    $req->execute(array('stock' =>$stock));
```

Comment: I'm not certain if this is what you're asking, but are you looking for `UPDATE ingredients SET stock = stock + 1 ...` ?

Comment: Do you mean `=:stock` should be `= {$stock}`? Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: @ThomasEdwards Definitely not.

Comment: it's a placeholder and that's just right @ThomasEdwards. Using your example the code will be susceptible to SQL injection

Answer (score 2):

When you click on the "+" button, It adds `+1` on your current stock, So you can update it with the current value like `stock = stock + 1`,

```
<?php 
$nom = 'salade';
$req=$db->prepare("UPDATE ingredients SET stock = stock + 1 WHERE nom =:nom");
$req->execute(array('nom' =>$nom));
?>
```

Comment: It works but it puts me not +1  but +8 always, it 's probably because I have  8  elements ( salade,tomatoes,...... )

Comment: @jacques if it adds 8 and you say you have 8 elements, that gives me the feeling that there is something wrong in your client side code that triggers this PHP script 8 times. Can you show us your JavaScript code that gets executed when you click on "+1" button.

Comment: yes , it's good it works now,  thx !!     But I would like know,  Why when I do F5  it refresh me the page, but  It add me too +1 ???